# 2017 sonic ticking

Tags: engine, chevrolet, sonic, tap

I have a 2017 Chevy sonic 1.4l turbo with 56000km / 35000mi that developed ticking sounds that I noticed after heavy foot to the peddle acceleration in a steep grade at a stop sign trying  to cross I to traffic.

The sound is very rapid.
Occurs at idle and while driving.*
Does not increase or decrease with acceration.
No cluster lights (check engine, temp, oil etc)
Does not occur when engine is cold, but starts ticking after hearing some sort of secondary mechanical noise that sounds as if something is being adjusted in the engine by the ecu.
Fuel efficiency has taken a considerable hit.

- Does NOT occur at 1500rpm. When using cruise, it will keep the engine at 1500rpm with slight deviation by a couple hundred, and this is when it will intermittently tick on and off. When breaking or accelerating, the ticking resumes at steady frequency.

update Nov 18 2019
malfunction indicator light came on
no boost (did not experience the turbo lag normally experienced during acceleration), but engine seems to run fine under load still.
engine almost stalled at idle @ ~800rpm, a guesstimate. That choking sound which ive heard before when removing a vacuum hose.

Update: Nov 18 2019

After waking up I started the car. Malfunction indicator light is off 
Opened the bonnet and noticed the sound is more of a ratcheting sound emanating at the rear of the engine.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PmlHCiyutJrnc6aUoXRSffklEyEm12JT/view?usp=drivesdk

I can isolate the sound to this part :

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QDzZxARgPsBuW9pVEP80WvmM7aKQtW70/view?usp=drivesdk which is plastic, I'm assuming is a cover for the exhaust manifold.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! A recording of the noise, while probably hard to obtain, would be of great benefit here.

Comment: this is the best I could get. I also got a malfunction indicator light tonight and a notification from  OnStar about engine and transmission problem. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PJLxOHXZYR--2Aa1XvlgysqU9ftUL-Xe/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: I don't have access to the two clips you put in the question, though I could listen to the one in your comment. The audio isn't helping much. If you can get the codes read, I'd bet that'd help with diagnosis. The actual codes, not the generic description you've posted here.

Comment: I've forgotten to turn link sharing on. It should be fixed now. You'll have to crank your volume. I've also an obd2 reader coming tomorrow.

Comment: codes p1101, p0171